# causality violation

Tags: time, causality, being-and-time

Any of you have ever analyzed causality violation: anti-arguments are obvious but I am asking for kind a strong support of this odd logic.
For example: If you don't think or do something today, your yesterday could have been different?

Comment: You can see [Causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_(physics)) and [Quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) and [Chronology protection conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_protection_conjecture).

Comment: Stephen Mumford & Rani Lill Anjum's "Causation A Very Short Introduction" may be relevant at least for quick survey of what possible answers should cover.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I believe those are best places in physics. But because there are still many fundamental issues which modern physics cannot address, e.g quantum physics on the large relativistic scales ..etc I put this question in rather a more general philosophical jurisdiction, if exists any at all.

Comment: @FrankHubeny: very nice book, it includes many interesting fundamental concepts. Thanks.